# The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString in the info.plist file must be period seperated list of at most three non-negative integers

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, cfbundleidentifier

While updating next version of build to appstore i am facing weird issue:

> "The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString "0.2.0.1" in the
>   info.plist file must be period seperated list of at most three
>   non-negative integers."

But i've checked in my entire app, i cannot see that version number. In plist i given is version :4.9 and build number: 50.

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Please search `CFBundleShortVersionString` in all projects. It's may be caused by 3rd parties or cocoapods libraries.

Comment: There is no such key in my pods info.plist.

Comment: Can you please share the .plist file over here.

Comment: <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
 <string>6.0</string>
 <key>CFBundleName</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
 <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
 <string>APPL</string>
 <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
 <string>4.9.0</string>
 <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
 <string>25</string>

Comment: Try Find ---> Find in Workspace ---> search for "0.2.0.1" to see if it is anywhere. If it really is nowhere, Product ---> Clean might do the trick...